# What would cause my segue to infinitely loop?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I've implemented a count-down timer that will automatically start my application if the user doesn't select any options. When the timer hits zero, I invalidate it and fire `performSegueWithIdentifier`, which segues me to my desired view.

At that point all is fine... well, sort of. I do notice that my view fires twice, but its fine after that. At this point, if I navigate away from that view, then back again, my segue fires and the view loads over and over until I stop my app.

**my output window shows:**

> 2015-05-13 21:20:26.880 Web App Browser[43407:7957566] Unbalanced
>   calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   . 2015-05-13
>   21:20:28.825 Web App Browser[43407:7957566] Unbalanced calls to
>   begin/end appearance transitions for .

**Here's my view controller:**

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController {

    var countDown = Bool()
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var count = 5
    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        countDown = AppDelegate().userDefaults.valueForKey("Auto Start") as! Bool

        if countDown == true {
            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        } else {
            countdownLabel.text = ""
        }      
    }

    func update() {
        countdownLabel.text = "\(count)"

        if count == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toWeb", sender: nil)
        } else {
            count--
        }
    }
}
```

**my storyboard:**

In the image below, you see my selected segue, which takes the user from the start screen into a navigation controller that has an embedded viewController. You'll note that I've added my Identifier as "toWeb".

[image]

### My Question:

What would cause my segue to infinitely loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this was pretty obvious, but my update was getting called every second... because i told it to. And I put my `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside it. So, easy fix.

```
var segueFlag = false

func update() {
        countdownLabel.text = "\(count)"

        if count == 0 {   
            timer.invalidate()

            if segueFlag == false {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toWeb", sender: nil)
                segueFlag = true
            }

        } else {
            count--
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is directly related to your issue, but you are declaring timer twice, once locally and once at class scope.

```
var countDown = Bool()
var timer = NSTimer()
var count = 5
@IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    countDown = AppDelegate().userDefaults.valueForKey("Auto Start") as! Bool

    if countDown == true {
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } else {
        countdownLabel.text = ""
    }      
}
```

you see the var timer = NSTimer() creates a timer at class scope

var timer = NSTimer.scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval... creates a new timer in the scope of viewDidLoad. I assume that should just be timer = NSTimer.scheduleTimer...